# Where is this data source address pointing to?

Tags: c#, oledb

```
    private static string GetConnectionString() 
    {
        return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                Data Source=.\\App_Data\\Halloween.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
    }
```

I've tried putting the `App_Data` folder in several places, and I've also tried switching the address up, but for some reason I have to been able to get the connection string to correctly point to the database I'm trying to use.

I was wondering if anyone knew exactly where this is looking at, so I'd know if I've just been putting it in the wrong spot.

Comment: Why not just change the connection string to wherever the database is?

Comment: The dot represents the current folder. So the connection string above will look for a file called Halloween.accdb in a folder called App_Data that's inside the current folder.